# Map autocomplete word in normal mode?

Tags: autocompletion, insert-mode, normal-mode

I want to map `,` in normal mode to function as autocompleting a word `<c-n>` in insert mode. Also, I want to keep pressing `,` in normal mode to cycle through the list and then finally when I finish after choosing a word to still stay in normal mode.

Is this possible? The only way I can think of is to first map to `i` to enter insert mode. But then I don't want `i` mapped again in future iterations of `,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic strategy is to use an expression mapping and check whether the popup menu is visible to issue the correct keys.

```
nnoremap <silent> , :call search('\w\>','cW')<cr>a<c-n>
inoremap <silent> <expr> , pumvisible() ? "\<c-n>" : ","
```

The normal mapping goes to the end of the word before trying to complete.

Comment: WOW! What if I also wanted to remain in normal mode after choosing?

Comment: What key press do you use to "choose" an entry?  Obviously pressing escape works already.  Two ideas would be to map <c-y> and <c-e> which are the "accept" and "cancel" commands, or add a `CompleteDone` autocommand which drops back to normal mode.  Both of these have side-effects though, and are more complicated to implement.  What about `inoremap <silent><expr> <cr> pumvisible() ? "\<c-y>\<esc>" : "<cr>"`